# lightblue Python module not working on mac

Tags: python, bluetooth

I'm trying to connect to wiimote via Python on mac osx 10.7.2.

For that I'm trying to use lightblue. When running: `import lightblue` Python gives me this error.

```
   >>> import lightblue
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightblue/__init__.py", line 160, in <module>
    from _lightblue import *
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightblue/_lightblue.py", line 27, in <module>
    import _IOBluetooth
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lightblue/_IOBluetooth.py", line 47, in <module>
    globals=globals())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/_bridgesupport.py", line 142, in initFrameworkWrapper
    _parseBridgeSupport(data, globals, frameworkName)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/_bridgesupport.py", line 42, in _parseBridgeSupport
    objc.parseBridgeSupport(data, globals, frameworkName, *args, **kwds)
ValueError: cftype for 'IOBluetoothDeviceInquiryRef' must include gettypeid_func, tollfree or both
```

I found one with a similar problem here: http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/Python-bridgesupport-issue-on-Lion-td2161049.html#a32196961 but the answer doesn't help me much, since it seems to me that it is already using lightblue's files. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a bug with Apple's `gen_bridge_metadata` script. You can make the error go away by editing the generated file by hand.

Open up `/System/Library/Frameworks/IOBluetooth.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/BridgeSupport/IOBluetooth.bridgesupport` and delete the lines that start with `<cftype`.

Comment: ImportError: Cannot load LightAquaBlue framework, not found at/Library/Frameworks/LightAquaBlue.framework